# What is the difference between LINQ lambda_method(Closure) and lambda_method(ExecutionScope)?

Tags: c#, linq

Recently I upgraded a solution from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.5. I am looking through the logs trying to identify a problem. When I look at the logs from the 3.5 deploy, I see the following LINQ error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at lambda_method(ExecutionScope )

Now, when I look at the logs from the 4.5 deploy, I see something very similar.

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at lambda_method(Closure )

I believe both of these errors are coming from the same line of code...

```
SomeCollection.Single(x => GetValue().ToString()); //GetValue() returns null.
```

However, I can't be 100% sure, because of this slight variance in the Exception message. (Closure vs. ExecutionScope) Can someone explain this discrepancy? Did something change between 3.5 and 4.5 with respect to this Exception message?

Comment: That's because .Net 4.0 changed the Expression Tree compilation process.

Comment: @SLaks Can you link to any source about that? That's quite interesting.